# Join data from different sheets by sheet name

Tags: google-sheets

I have google sheet with multiple sheets. all have the same data columns with same names  (id , date, amount)  but in different columns:
in sheet 1 "id" column is A , in sheet be "id" column can be column C or any other column.

Im trying to create a Master sheet taking all data from all the sheets and arranging it by column name.
Tryied using Query but it seems it can work with columns IDs (A , B ) which is changing in my case.

[here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RTCazkAjXx0Q5GhdxrmTk92dFz9IQUqha8zyw6RDKI4/edit?usp=sharing) a sample sheet

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, and using a straightforward/easy approach: you can understand that you need to build 3 queries then combine them as follows:

[image]

```
={
  query({Sheet1!A3:C4},"Select * ");
      query({'Sheet2 '!A2:C4},"Select Col2,Col1,Col3 ");
          query({Sheet3!A2:C4},"Select Col2,Col3,Col1 ")
 }
```

`"Select * "`: means select everything in the same order the range is defined. Which can be replaced by `"Select Col1,Col2,Col3 "`

Comment: Tnx
but my real sheet has dozens of sheets and I need to gather the info of around 10 columns (that i know the name off.. but not where they are in the sheet). so I need to refer them by the columns "name" ( ID , Name , Type etc) and not by the Coumn number